# Completion popup closes after pressing Enter twice

Tags: qt-creator, fakevim

I'm using **Qt Creator 3.1.1** with FakeVim mode enabled.

When the completion popup appears with the desired function already as the first one, I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice in order to insert text. The same thing happens when I want to insert more letters before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I have to press first key twice, than everything goes as expected (following keys require single presses, <kbd>Enter</kbd> too).

ex. I entered `avform` and the popup appeared. If I want the first tooltip `AVFormatContext` i press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice. If I want `avformat_smthing` I need to press `aaform_` cause the first <kbd>a</kbd> will like change mode back to insert (but not really as I'm still in INSERT mode).

I wonder if anybody stumbled upon similar problem/inconvenience, and what can I do to change QtCreator behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's a known bug, and it hasn't been fixed yet. It only appears in newer versions of Qt-creator (`>2.8.1`). Partial fix is to disable autocompletion or unmark `Pass keys in insert mode` but both options have side effects (ex.<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> opens completion popup, but the text doesn't get inserted).

Link to: [Issue on BugTracker](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11619) for curious.